# Stacked Autoencoder for classification using mnist

Tags: keras

Am aware that container for autoencoder has been removed in new Keras. My aim is to extract the encoding representation of an input and feed it in as an input to the next layer i.e. stacked autoencoder for classification using three hidden layers. I got this error:

Exception: Error when checking model target: expected dense_160 to have shape (None, 500) but got array with shape (60000L, 784L). I am not too sure if this code achieves my intention.  I will appreciate any guide on how to resolve this. Thanks.
The code is pasted below:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch=200
batch_size=256
hidden_layer1=784
hidden_layer2=600
hidden_layer3=500
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))
print('Train samples: {}'.format(x_train.shape[0]))
print('Test samples: {}'.format(x_test.shape[0]))

from keras.utils import np_utils
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(hidden_layer1, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(hidden_layer2, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded=Dense(hidden_layer3,activation='softmax')(encoded)
model = Model(input=input_img , output=encoded) 
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, x_train,
            nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

print('Test score before fine turning:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy after fine turning:', score[1])
```

Comment: @Tang Quoc Thai: Not an answer. Your script is not training the network with x_train as the output at any stage, so this doesn't work as an autoencoder at any point.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and tested, it worked.

```
nb_classes = 10
nb_epoch = 5
batch_size = 256
hidden_layer1 = 128
hidden_layer2 = 64
hidden_layer3 = 10 # because you have 10 categories
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))
print('Train samples: {}'.format(x_train.shape[0]))
print('Test samples: {}'.format(x_test.shape[0]))

from keras.utils import np_utils

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(hidden_layer1, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(hidden_layer2, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(hidden_layer3, activation='softmax')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(hidden_layer2, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(hidden_layer1, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

model = Model(input=input_img, output=encoded)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          shuffle=True,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)

print('/n')
print('Test score before fine turning:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy after fine turning:', score[1])
```

Comment: How did you modify it? A little explanation on what you've changed, and why, will make this a useful answer to others.

Comment: I change the size of hidden_layer3 = 10 because we have 10 digits.